# Removing line that contains more than one word

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to remove a line in a specified file if it has more than one word in it using a bash script in linux.

e.g. file:

```
$ cat testfile

This is a text
file

This line should be deleted
this-should-not.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, here's a pure bash version which doesn't call any other executable (since you asked for it in bash):

```
$ while read a b; do if [ -z "$b" ]; then echo $a;fi;done <testfile
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk 'NF<=1{print}' testfile`

a word being a run of non-whitespace.

Comment: Not what the requestor is asking: should be `awk 'NF==1' testfile`

Comment: @Glenn, oops, right. Thanks for the correction! But I think the right condition is `NF<=1`, so lines with *no* words are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!/[ \t]/{print $1}' testfile
```

This reads "print the first element of lines that don't contain a space or a tab".
Empty lines will be output (since they don't contain more than one word).

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough:

```
$ egrep -v '\S\s+\S' testfile
```

Comment: `grep -v '[[:space:]]'` perhaps, to catch all whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks @Lars, updated - people should note however that this may not work on non-GNU grep.

Comment: what about spaces at the beginning or end of a line?

Comment: @Kim See my other answer for a pure bash version that can handle spaces at the beginning or end of a line, although it does remove those spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '/ /d' << EOF
> This is a text
> file
> 
> This line should be deleted
> this-should-not.
> EOF
file

this-should-not.
```

Comment: this will break if the file has tabs instead of spaces. Perhaps `sed '/[[:space:]]/d` if the sed regex syntax allows it.

Answer (score 0):

This should satisfy your needs:

```
cat filename | sed -n '/^\S*$/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit files in-place (without any backups), you may also use `man ed`:

```
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s testfile
H
,g/^[[:space:]]*/s///
,g/[[:space:]]*$/s///
,g/[[:space:]]/.d
wq
EOF
```